# Updating Value of Array Element in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'd like to know how to update the "value" field of one of the elements identified by the "name" field in the array "array_of_stuff".  For example, I want to update the value for "name_of_thing_1" to "new_value_of_thing_1".  How can I do this **ONLY** using the second parameter (i.e. the update parameter) to the update command.  I am re-using a class library written in-house I don't have control over the first argument to the update command (i.e. the query parameter).  Is this possible?

```
{
"array_of_stuff": [
    {
        "name": "name_of_thing_1",
        "value": "value_of_thing_1",           
    },
    {
        "name": "name_of_thing_2",
        "value": "value_of_thing_2",
    }
]
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 12):

You can update the value of a single item in an array (if you know its index) like this:

```
db.stuff.update(/* query ... */, {$set:{"arrayname.<index>":new_value}})
```

If your array contains documents, you can update a particular field of a document at that index like this:

```
db.stuff.update(/* query ... */, {$set:{"array_of_stuff.0.value":"new_value_of_thing_1"}})

// If you could use the query parameter and knew something
// about the value in the array you wanted to change:
db.stuff.update({"array_of_stuff.value":"value_of_thing_1"}, {$set:{"array_of_stuff.$.value":"new_value_of_thing_1"}})
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this example help you:

```
db.bruno.insert({"array": [{"name": "Hello", "value": "World"}, {"name": "Joker", "value": "Batman"}]})

db.bruno.update({"array.name": "Hello"}, {$set: {"array.$.value": "Change"}})

db.bruno.find().pretty()
```

output:

```
db.bruno.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52389faaafd72821e7b25a73"),
    "array" : [
        {
            "name" : "Hello",
            "value" : "Change"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Joker",
            "value" : "Batman"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible. In order to update field of one of the elements in array, you should use positional $ operator, e.g.:

```
update({'array_of_stuff.name':'name_of_thing_1'}, 
       { $set: {'array_of_stuff.$.value':'new_value_of_thing_1'}})
```

But [according to documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/#op._S_): positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the first element that matches query document, and the array field **must appear as part of the query document**.