# How to update specified Document in MongoDB with Javascript

Tags: mongodb

I have a document like this:

```
[ { _id: 55535305c6d17454276beba1,
    name: 'Localhost',
    tables: [{ chairs:[{
                         data:[{
                         }]
                      }]
            }] 
  }
]
```

I want to update/insert new data in the data document.

Comment: Deep nested document is not a good idea. Your document structure will not make your life easier. You definitely going to have head explosion

Comment: i cant change this structure and yes i have a head explosion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along these lines for your example:

```
db.collectionName.update(
    {_id: 55535305c6d17454276beba1}, 
    {$set: {"tables.chairs.data" : [{somethingHere:1}] }}
);
```

You can update individual elements in the data array by using this syntax:

```
db.collectionName.update(
    {_id: 55535305c6d17454276beba1}, 
    {$set: {"tables.chairs.data.0" : {somethingHere:2} }}
);
```

This link provides some additional examples:
[Updating Value of Array Element in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856961/updating-value-of-array-element-in-mongodb)